# Accurate progress update using FFmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm currently showing the progress inside `onProgress`, as shown below:

```
@Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("time=([\\d\\w:]{8}[\\w.][\\d]+)");

        if (message.contains("speed")) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);

            if (matcher.find()) {
                String tempTime = String.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
                String[] arrayTime = tempTime.split("[:|.]");

                long currentTime = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[0]))
                            + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[1]))
                            + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[2]))
                            + Long.parseLong(arrayTime[3]);

                //Length of video in milliseconds
                long timeToExportInMillis = rightThumbTimeRef - leftThumbTimeRef;

                //Calculate percentage
                long percent = 100 * currentTime / timeToExportInMillis;

                //Set percentage to TextView
                percentText.setText(percent + " %");

            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that the progress gets updated like this:

`0 - 9 - 17 - 30 - 38` etc. (till 100)

I would like to show the progress without skipping values, like:

`0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4` etc. (till 100)

---

I'm not even sure if this is possible because the update of `currentTime` (above) depends on FFmpeg's progress output, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: ffmpeg updates progress every 0.5 seconds. So if processing speed is greater than 2% per sec, then you have to interpolate. But then your indicator will be wrong if speed isn't near-constant.

Comment: @Gyan is it possible to "force" ffmpeg to update the progress more frequently?

Comment: No, it's hardcoded. Either stick with the current steps. Or measure current processing speed and interpolate to provide finer progress updates.

Comment: @Gyan one last question, if you don't mind. Does ffmpeg always update the progress exactly every 0.5 seconds or does it differ?

Comment: Unless it's hung, progress is updated every 0.5 seconds.